# Group and Merge multiple values from single List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following enums and class

```
internal enum flag_dead_alive
{
    none = 0
    ,
    dead = 1
    ,
    alive = 2
}

internal enum flag_blocked_unblocked
{
    none = 0
    ,
    blocked = 1
    ,
    unblocked = 2
}

internal class cls_entry
{
    internal string id_number { get; set; }

    internal flag_dead_alive dead_alive { get; set; }

    internal flag_blocked_unblocked blocked_unblocked { get; set; }
}
```

I have List which contains hundreds of thousands of records, so for testing purposes I have created a sample list that contain the same sort of records, below (id_number is deliberately set as string for reasons that are irrelevant right now)

```
List<cls_npr_entry> output = new List<cls_npr_entry>()
            {
                new cls_npr_entry() { id_number = "1", dead_alive = flag_dead_alive.alive, blocked_unblocked = flag_blocked_unblocked.none }
                ,
                new cls_npr_entry() { id_number= "1", dead_alive = flag_dead_alive.none, blocked_unblocked= flag_blocked_unblocked.blocked }
                ,
                new cls_npr_entry(){id_number= "2", dead_alive = flag_dead_alive.none, blocked_unblocked= flag_blocked_unblocked.blocked }
                ,
                new cls_npr_entry(){id_number= "3", dead_alive = flag_dead_alive.dead, blocked_unblocked= flag_blocked_unblocked.none }
                ,
                new cls_npr_entry(){id_number= "3", dead_alive = flag_dead_alive.none, blocked_unblocked= flag_blocked_unblocked.unblocked }
            };
```

From the list, I want to get output of grouped and merged (is that the correct term here?) records from my list. However, any enum that is set to "none" should be discarded if a matched record has a different value to "none", otherwise it must remain "none". For example, the output for the above list should be

```
1 : id_number = 1, dead_alive = alive, blocked_unblocked = blocked
2 : id_number = 2, dead_alive = none, blocked_unblocked = blocked
3 : id_number = 3, dead_alive = dead, blocked_unblocked = unblocked
```

The code

```
var groups = output.GroupBy(x => x.id_number);
```

returns the records in the correct groups, but I have no idea where to from here.  I also have

```
var groups = output.GroupBy(x => x.id_number).Select(g => g.Select(y => new { y.id_number, y.blocked_unblocked, y.dead_alive }));
```

but that returns the same result as the first query. I need to figure out how to select one record from y.dead_alive and one record from y.blocked_unblocked, so that the result only returns only the relevant record to create one record from both.

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `output`test list, you can get the`Max` of `dead_alive` and `blocked_unblocked` after grouping, like the following code:

```
var groups = output.GroupBy(x => x.id_number)
    .Select(y => new cls_entry
    {
        id_number = y.Key,
        dead_alive = y.Max(e => e.dead_alive),
        blocked_unblocked = y.Max(e => e.blocked_unblocked)
    }).ToList();
```

Documentation of `Max` method : [Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Wow, works like a charm, thank you so much! You don't want to see the lines and lines of code I tried... I am still in the midst of the LINQ mind shift, I didn't even think of using Max, in my mind it is a numeric operator but it makes sense, enums do indicate numeric values. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome, you can change also the ``y.First().id_number`` by ``y.key`` like my update

Comment: Will do thanks. Nothing wrong with your first version, but the update seems more "in line with convention" and elegant.